# VPS cant show image within the name ÆØÅ

Tags: wordpress, webserver, server, vps, plesk

I just moved my webshop(wordpress), to a VPS located on Unoeuro. The problem is that after i moved it, it can't show half of my images, because the letters ÆØÅ(Danish Charchters) is in the URL of the image.

My url on the image can be something like: oral_b_eltandbørste_crossaction_pro_5000_2-150x150.jpg

If i change the "ø" to "o" it works. But i need to set the VPS up to handle ÆØÅ, so i dont need to change the adress on 3000 images.

If i buy a webhotel at unoeuro, it works with the charchters ÆØÅ.

So my question is, how can i fix this problem? do i need to change the server UFT?

My server runs with Plesk, and parrels power panel.

Its my first time with an VPS, so please make a good explanation.

Comment: do the symbols appear correctly on your webpage?

Comment: David, they show like they should :-(

Comment: How this files looks on file system? ls -la oral_b_eltandbørste_crossaction_pro_5000_2-150x150.jpg?

Comment: If you using zip to archiving site folder, it's may be reason https://allencch.wordpress.com/2013/04/15/extracting-files-from-zip-which-contains-non-utf8-filename-in-linux/